# ssh into a vm to pentest another vm on a different subnet

Tags: networking, ssh, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I'm trying to pentest [this machine](https://www.vulnhub.com/entry/breach-1,152/) (**guest target**) who has been configured to be on 192.168.110.140 with the Host-only networking feature of virtualbox.

I can access it from my host machine, no worries until here.

This host machine is on 192.168.1.195, but this is not the machine I use to test : I use for that another vm with Kali (**guest attacker**) on it and I configured it with a bridged connection, because most of the time I want to ssh into that VM.

Now the issue is that from **guest attacker** I can't access the **guest target** that is on another subnet.

If I configure guest attacker to use the NAT I now can ping the guest target fine, but I can't ssh from the host into the guest attacker.

What config should I have to:

- be able to ssh from host to guest attacker AND
- see guest target from guest attacker knowing I'm forced to use the Host-only feature as the ip seems to have been set in stone on that VM....

Comment: Setup 2 vNICs on your guest attacker (one NAT, one Host only).

Comment: Is the real problem here that you want to be able to change the target machine from host-only to bridged or some other networking?  Or if it must be host-only on that interface, why not add a second interface on the target and attack VMs and use Internal networking to set up a private network between the two?

Comment: I ended up removing the bridged connection on the guest attacker, replaced it with a NAT and port forward (so that I can ssh into it from host)